# CoreLocation stops getting updates after idling

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, core-location

I have an app that collects lat/long coordinates ONLY using the GPS chip in an iPad (IE no wifi or cellular on ios8). It seems to work consistently unless the app is idled for about an hour (The app is still opened but the iPad locks.) Here is my code

I call     `[self.locman startUpdatingLocation];` in an IBAction upon pressing a UIButton that gets the coordinates and stores them to a text file in the documents directory.

```
// Delegate method from the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol.
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    // If it's a relatively recent event, turn off updates to save power.
    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
    NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (abs(howRecent) < 1) {
        self.lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",location.coordinate.latitude];
        self.longString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",location.coordinate.longitude];
        [self.locman stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
```

Also if it doesn't get updates after a hour long hiatus, the app will subsequently get updates if the user presses the button again within an hour. So it seems to be a warming up issue.

To clarify. It seems to be a timing issue. For testing purposes I would collect coordinates....drive for 5 minutes, and collect coordinates. I could do this plenty of times with ~a 5 min interval in between stops. This would work perfectly, regardless of the screen turning blank or me pressing the 'sleep' button. The issue arises when I leave the ipad alone for around an hour (way longer than 5 minutes). Then the app will give me coordinates of 0.000000 and 0.0000000.

Here is the instantiation for my location manager.

```
self.locman = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    //self.locman.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
    self.locman.delegate = self;
    self.locman.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locman.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locman.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
```

Comment: So the problem you are facing is that the location is not updating when the app is open but iPad is locked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't stop updating the location for recent updates, let the framework handle the frequency. It's a good idea to check the time stamp to make sure you don't have old location data -- the location manager typically delivers previously cached location data immediately and then delivers more up-to-date location data as it becomes available.

Which iOS version is this? In iOS 8, you will need to call `requestAlwaysAuthorization` in order to receive location updates in the background.

Can you give more details on how you have set up your location manager?

It's possible that your app is being killed by the system after a certain time. This could happen if there is a memory leak.

Comment: Please see my edit for how I set up the location manager. Also, I am using ios8. Also in my original code I am checking the timestamp to throw out the cached data; it just doesn't work after a long period of time. Perhaps I have to make 'howRecent' higher? I'll try seeing what commenting out 'stopUpdatingLocation' does. Although I believe this will just yield multiple coordinates because the location manager never stops (a behavior I don't want)

Comment: In your original code, you are stopping the location manager from updating when the time stamp is recent. If you do that, `self.lat` and `self.longString` will be set once, when the time stamp is recent enough, and then you'll stop receiving updates unless you restart elsewhere. Additionally, you're setting `self.locman.desiredAccuracy` twice; the first statement is ignored.